Using QgsProcessingParameterEnum in QGIS Python processing script
I am currently working on a processing script for QGIS. In the function def initAlgorithm() I am defining several parameters. One of the parameters is using QgsProcessingParameterEnum with a pre-defined list:
# Function to initialize the algorithm/tool
def initAlgorithm(self, config=None):
    self.addParameter(
        QgsProcessingParameterEnum(
            "CHOICE_LAYER", 'Title', options=['A', 'B'], defaultValue='A'
             )
        )

This works so far and I can select the values in the GUI. The problem is in the further processing of the selection. In the function processAlgorithm() I try to get the value from the GUI by using the following lines.
def processAlgorithm(self, parameters, context, feedback):
    # Get value from the GUI        
    choice = self.parameterAsString(parameters, "CHOICE_LAYER", context)
    print(f"{choice }")

This is also works, but returns the index position of the value from the choice list. So selecting "A" returns 0 and selecting "B" returns 1.
Is there a way to get the "real" value and not only the index?
I also tried self.parameterAsEnumString() but this only returns every time the value "A"...

Set usesStaticStrings=True when you create the parameter:
class ExampleProcessingAlgorithm(QgsProcessingAlgorithm):
    # etc...

    def initAlgorithm(self, config=None):
        self.addParameter(
            QgsProcessingParameterEnum(
                "CHOICE_LAYER", 'Title', options=['A', 'B'], defaultValue='A', 
                usesStaticStrings=True  #<----------- here
            )
        )

    def processAlgorithm(self, parameters, context, feedback):
        # Get value from the GUI        
        choice = self.parameterAsString(parameters, "CHOICE_LAYER", context)
        print(f"{choice}")
        # etc.....



Alternatively, you could create a list of the choices and assign it to an instance attribute then use the index to get the string value, e.g.
class ExampleProcessingAlgorithm(QgsProcessingAlgorithm):
    # etc...

    def initAlgorithm(self, config=None):
        self._CHOICE_LAYER = ["A", "B"]  # <==== instance attribute
        self.addParameter(
            QgsProcessingParameterEnum(
                "CHOICE_LAYER", 'Title', options=self._CHOICE_LAYER, defaultValue=self._CHOICE_LAYER[0]
            )
        )

    def processAlgorithm(self, parameters, context, feedback):
        # Get value from the GUI        
        choice = self.parameterAsInt(parameters, "CHOICE_LAYER", context)  # <===== param as int

        print(f"{choice} {self._CHOICE_LAYER[choice]}")
        # etc.....



